# Code generation via sibling file in micro-service

Tags: c#, templates, microservices, code-generation, boilerplate

Is there a nuget that, via command line (like EF Tools does with add-migration), could generate "sibling" code (aka boilerplate) from the information contained in my Entities (name and properties)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with **T4 Text Templates**, which basically consists in placing a .tt file in each folder.
In order to create the corresponding files for each entity, I had to use some reflection (this part was tricky)

Big thanks to whoever originally created the **SaveOutput** method.

I paste here a working template. A very simple one for better understanding.
If you are using Resharper, I recommend you installing the **ForTea** plugin. Otherwise, it becomes very difficult dealing with the template.

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)MyProject.Shared.Domain.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)MyProject.Shared.Common.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)MyProject.Domain.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="MyProject.Shared.Common.Helpers" #>
<#@ import namespace="MyProject.Shared.Common.Extensions" #>
<#@ import namespace="MyProject.Shared.Domain.Entities" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#
var types = FileHelper.GetTypes(typeof(IEntity),Assembly.LoadFrom(typeof(IEntity).Assembly.CodeBase.Replace("MyProject.Shared.Domain.dll","") +  "MyProject.Domain.dll"));
foreach (var type in types) {

if(new[]
{
    //////// Exclude ////////
    "a"
    //, "b"
    //, "c"
    /////////////////////////
}.Any(c => type.Name.Contains(c))) continue;

////////////////////////////////////////////// Your code //////////////////////////////////////////////
#>
namespace MyProject.Application.Messages
{
    public static class <#=type.Name#>Message
    {
        public const string <#=type.Name#>NotFound = "The <#=type.Name.ToReadable()#> does not exist";
        public const string <#=type.Name#>AlreadyExists = "The <#=type.Name.ToReadable()#> already exists";
    }
}
<#
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

SaveOutput(type.Name + "Message.cs");
}
#>
<#+
private void SaveOutput(string outputFileName) {
var templateDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
if (templateDirectory == null) return;
var outputFilePath = Path.Combine(templateDirectory, outputFileName);
if(!File.Exists(outputFilePath)) File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString()); 
GenerationEnvironment.Remove(0, GenerationEnvironment.Length);
}
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to use a code generator to produce all the boilerplate code.
Despite many code generators use their own model to define domain entities it could be efficient and save a lot of workload.

Some tools like Telosys (https://www.telosys.org/) with C# templates ( https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/csharp-web-mvc ) are usable for .Net projects.

In your case you will just have to redefine your entities in a DSL model ( see https://www.telosys.org/dsl-syntax.html it's quite simple)

See also this responses :
[How to generate whole boiler plate code for CRUD operations like visual studio using code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209315/how-to-generate-whole-boiler-plate-code-for-crud-operations-like-visual-studio-u/)